# How to programatically add floating header bar to a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uikit

Okay, someone please shed some light here. I am very new to coding, still. Ive been learning swift for about a month or so and have taken the route of designing my first super simple app as my learning path. This gives me purpose that other app builds lacked but is a different learning curve in and of itself.

In this situation I have created almost my entire UI in Xcode Interface Builder using auto-layout and graphics. This creates the situation where there is no code at all for the UI. Great and simple to learn fast however, now I need to do something programmatically (so it seems) and I don't even know where to start.

I have a scrollview, it puts out about 100 lines of calculations, in 9 columns. The view is larger and scrolling vertical and horizontal. I also have a label header describing each column. When the user scrolls down (data up) it is impossible to keep track of which column is which because the label header disappears. I am trying to figure out how to add a floating header to my scrollview just like you would "freeze" a header in spreadsheets.

Thus far I've tried everything I could in Interface Builder, all the searches I've done turn up only programmatic solutions, which is fine except that I have no UI code to attach to...

So I really have one question:

How do you add a floating header in UI Builder OR programmatically when there is no initial code? I want my labels horizontal stackview to sit still as a floating header.

Any help is much appreciated, been racking my head over this the last 3 whole days and its the last change before I'm done my app :(

Edit: here is my code and a few screenshots of initial view, scroll right and scroll down. As you can see there is no UI code really. I want to do something like this but not with a tableView: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/adding-a-fixed-header-to-a-uiscrollview
Even more ideally something like this but not with a table or collectionView... https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnCqL.jpg

[image: calculate button pressed] [image] [image]

```
import UIKit

class MetricVerticalViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var shelfHeight: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var squeezeFour: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var squeezeThree: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var squeezeTwo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var squeezeOne: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var normalGauge: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gainOne: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gainTwo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gainThree: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gainFour: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    shelfHeight.delegate = self
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

// Calculate button tapped will cause math to occur and the text field to show the values
@IBAction func calculateSpacing(_ sender: UIButton) {
    squeezeFour.text = ""
    squeezeThree.text = ""
    squeezeTwo.text = ""
    squeezeOne.text = ""
    normalGauge.text = ""
    gainOne.text = ""
    gainTwo.text = ""
    gainThree.text = ""
    gainFour.text = ""
    // Resigns the keyboard when the button is pressed
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    calculateSpacing()
    
}
// Acts to dismiss number keyboard when user taps outside
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    brickHeight.resignFirstResponder()
}

func calculateSpacing() {
    let shelfHeight = Int(shelfHeight.text!) ?? 1
    let squeezeFourGauge = shelfHeight + 6
    let squeezeThreeGauge = shelfHeight + 7
    let squeezeTwoGauge = shelfHeight + 8
    let squeezeOneGauge = shelfHeight + 9
    let normalJoint = shelfHeight + 10
    let gainOneGauge = shelfHeight + 11
    let gainTwoGauge = shelfHeight + 12
    let gainThreeGauge = shelfHeight + 13
    let gainFourGauge = shelfHeight + 14
    for index in 1...100 {
        squeezeFour.text! += "Shelf \(index) = \(index * squeezeFourGauge)\n"
        squeezeThree.text! += "Shelf \(index) = \(index * squeezeThreeGauge)\n"
        squeezeTwo.text! += "Shelf \(index) = \(index * squeezeTwoGauge)\n"
        squeezeOne.text! += "Shelf \(index) = \(index * squeezeOneGauge)\n"
        normalGauge.text! += "Shelf \(index) = \(index * normalJoint)\n"
        gainOne.text! += "Shelf \(index) = \(index * gainOneGauge)\n"
        gainTwo.text! += "Shelf \(index) = \(index * gainTwoGauge)\n"
        gainThree.text! += "Shelf \(index) = \(index * gainThreeGauge)\n"
        gainFour.text! += "Shelf \(index) = \(index * gainFourGauge)\n"
    }
}


extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {

// Acts to dismiss keyboard once user presses return (possibly unnecessary as this was used for text keyboard input in original code)
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. Then edit your question with a [example] showing what specific part you are having a problem with. Your question is currently way too broad.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've added some code and screenshots to better describe. I am confused myself  as to exactly what to do so its hard to describe... Thanks for understanding :)

Comment: Please ask only question per topic.

Comment: Adjusted, thanks koen

Answer (score 0):

One way to access Interface Builder items from code is via an outlet connection. You have to open your code next to Interface Builder, then control-drag the item into your view controller code and make sure to choose "Outlet" as the connection type. See [Apple's tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ConnectingObjectstoCode.html) for more info.

Comment: so what you're saying is that I could create an outlet for the scrollview and inside that outlet I can access properties and other programmatic properties?

Comment: Yes, by creating an outlet in the view controller code, you can access the referenced view programmatically (I would recommend doing so in the `viewDidLoad` method).

Answer (score 0):

So I did a little work and was actually able to create a floating header of the sizes in the above screenshots by adding a second view to the scrollview and constraining it like crazy. It worked great in the iPhone 11 Pro Max size because it was constrained using that size but then every other device was screwed up. I will try and set "vary for traits" constraints for other sizes and see if its a stable workaround.

If it works again i'll post some kind of write-up.

Apparently its bad to have more than one view inside a scrollView... worked okay for me.

Anyone else have any better solutions to this?